# Trouble with looping through lines of Input File in C

Tags: c

I am trying to run my tokenize function through different lines of my input file.

```
void
tokenize(FILE *src, char* buffer)
{

  fprintf(stdout,"%s\n", buffer);
  int i = 0;
  while  ( buffer[i] != '\n'){
    if(buffer[i] == ' '){
      i++  ;
    }else if (buffer[i]=='+'){
      fprintf(stdout,"+    Addition operator\n");
      i++;
    }else if (buffer[i]=='-'){
      fprintf(stdout,"-    Subtraction operator\n");
      i++;
    }else if (buffer[i]=='*'){
      fprintf(stdout,"*    Multiplication operator\n");
      i++;
    }else if (buffer[i]=='/'){
      fprintf(stdout,"-    Division operator\n");
      i++;
    }else if (buffer[i]=='^'){
      fprintf(stdout,"-    Exponentiation operator\n");
      i++;
    }else if( buffer[i]== '>'){
      if(buffer[i+=1] == '='){
    fprintf(stdout, ">=    Comparison Operator\n");
    i+=2;
      }else{
    fprintf(stdout,">    Comparison Operator\n");
    i+=1;
      }
    }else if( buffer[i]== '<'){
      if(buffer[i+=1] == '='){
    fprintf(stdout, "<=    Comparison Operator\n");
    i+=2;
      }else{
    fprintf(stdout,"<    Comparison Operator\n");
    i+=1;
      }
    }else if (isdigit((int)buffer[i])){
      fprintf(stdout, "%c    Simple Numeral\n",buffer[i]);
      i++;
    }else if (buffer[i] == ')'){
      i++;
    }else if (buffer[i] == '('){
      i++;
    }
  }
}

int
main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

  FILE* src = input_from_args(argc, argv);
  char str[80];
  while(fgets(str, 80, src) && fgetc(src)!=EOF){
    tokenize(src, str);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I feel like I'm on the right track based off of previous experiences. Doing loops through input files always confuse me. So far, it only goes through the first line.

Comment: Since the `tokenize()` function doesn't read anything from the input, there is no need to pass `FILE *src` to it.  Note that `fgets()` reads the newline; the `fgetc()` in the main function mostly throws away the first character on every line after the first, assuming the lines are shorter than 80 bytes each.  Eventually, you'll need to make your code handle longer lines (4096 is a good number to use — but it is even better not to place any limit on the length of line).  But that (line length) is not your main problem at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear why you pass `src` to `tokenize()`, since you never use this variable here. Consider compiling your code with `-Wall` and it should help catch issues like these.

Comment: The lines `}else if( buffer[i]== '>'){
      if(buffer[i+=1] == '='){
    fprintf(stdout, ">=    Comparison Operator\n");
    i+=2;
      }  }else{
    fprintf(stdout,">    Comparison Operator\n");
    i+=1;
      }` are odd; you unconditionally increment `i` before you know whether you really want to, and then you increment it by 2, which surely skips some data, and the else clause also increments past a character.

Comment: Doing `i+=1` in indexing expression leads to unpredicted results. You should either do `i+1` when testing for `'='` in `">="` and `"<="` **or** rethink thoroughly how you increment `i` afterwards.

Comment: As a basic security precaution, the loop `while (buffer[i] != '\n'){` should be `while (buffer[i] != '\0' && buffer[i] != '\n'){`, just in case the line was to long to fit in the buffer and was truncated before the newline was added to it.

Answer (score 2):

This following line behaves in a way that you probably didn't intend it to.

```
while(fgets(str, 80, src) && fgetc(src)!=EOF){
```

It will eat away the first character of every line except the first one and will skip over processing of the last line.

You need

```
while(fgets(str, 80, src) != NULL){
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you might want to be using something like [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) to read in a line at a time and parse. See example code in man page for more info.